# Пользователь базы данных postgresql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть **owner** базы данных, нужно добавить еще одного пользователя с такими же правами. Если конкретно то с правами на `update/delete/alter` и т.д.
Как это возможно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Данная команда позволит создать суперюзер, у которого будут права owner`а.

```
$ createuser --interactive *username*
```

Также можно создать роль через `CREATE ROLE` и, используя `--role=...`, создать нового пользователя с нужными правами.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать нового пользователя членом «группы» `owner`:

```
CREATE ROLE my_coowner LOGIN INHERIT;
GRANT owner TO my_coowner;
```

[Подробности](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/role-membership.html); [CREATE ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createrole.html); [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-grant.html);

---

Если нужен полностью независимый пользователь с точно такими же правами, то AFAIK готового ничего нет, придётся вручную (или полуавтоматически) давать ему точно такие же права на все объекты БД.